# setSelecteableDays Material DateTime Picker android

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm trying to use the Material `DateTimePicker` library.

The problem is that when I set a `minDate` and `maxDate` in the `datePicker` and an array of selectable dates the `dataPicker` does not show what I'm aspected

```
            Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            minDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
            minDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
            minDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

            Calendar maxDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            maxDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
            maxDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
            maxDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);

            Calendar aDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            maxDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
            maxDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
            maxDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 26);

            Calendar aDate1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            maxDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
            maxDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
            maxDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 22);

            Calendar[] availableDate = new Calendar[2];
            availableDate[0] = aDate;
            availableDate[1] = aDate1;

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(ProvaDatePicker.this, availableDate[0].get(Calendar.YEAR), availableDate[0].get(Calendar.MONTH), availableDate[0].get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            datePickerDialog.setMinDate(minDate);
            datePickerDialog.setMaxDate(maxDate);
            datePickerDialog.setSelectableDays(availableDate);
            datePickerDialog.setTitle("Available date");
            datePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "title");
```

This is the result[image]

Comment: What are you expecting setting setSelectableDays()?

Comment: I expecting DatePicker where the only dates clickable are those in available Date array

Comment: but why so the DataPicker show me only one month and not the rest of the months that i setted with the minDate and maxDate?

Comment: i've added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the dates in your code with YEAR to 2016, then in your screenshot you show that the YEAR is 2017.

To see the two enabled days you need to go to May 2016 or change the YEAR of your Calendar instances

You have the wrong assignement:

```
 Calendar aDate = Calendar.getInstance();
 maxDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
 maxDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
 maxDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 26);

 Calendar aDate1 = Calendar.getInstance();
 maxDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
 maxDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
 maxDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 22);
```

Here you should use `aDate` and `aDate1` assignment, while you are assigning them to `maxDate` again and again

Comment: I know, but the problem is why also if i create an instance of DatePickerDialog with the first date available in the array it show me the current date? i can't go to the May 2016 because the DatePicker show me only the may 2017

Comment: updated my answer. PS: to change Year you probably need to click on the year in the top left and a year selection should appear

Comment: Alla fine era una piccola cazzata ahahah :D Buona fortuna